# Incorrect date of birth in Job Offer

Tags: job-offer, new-job, human-resources, contracts

I have recently been provided with a written job offer from a German company to sign. While applying for the job during the application process, there was an issue with the website so I was only able to select the first of the month in the DOB field. Suppose my date of birth is April 15, I could only be able to select April 1. I didn't bother much since I was applying to many companies in a hurry.

Now, after all the interviews, the company has given me a contract with incorrect date of birth which has to be signed within a week.

I have to ask the HR now to modify the DOB in the contract. I am already feeling so embarrassed to ask HR about it.

My question is do HR have to make a new contract and get the sign of my manager and director again or can this be rectified simply by writing a note on the same contract.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Update : I have talked to HR. She asked me to fill a form on joining date and she will make the corrections. Sweet! Thanks for help!

Comment: Talk to HR, they will decide what they need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making a too big fuss about this, I would say. I would consider it a typo and ask the HR to correct it, just phrase the email/letter in an ambiguous way as where the typo arose from, like:

> *(Thank you for the contract.... blablabla polite stuff)* Unfortunately, there is a typo in my date of birth. The month and year are correct, but the day is incorrect. It should be 15 April 1888. *... blablabla polite stuff.*

This way you don't blame anyone, typos in contracts/forms/... appear all the time and people are used to correcting them.

---

Considering informing them about the bug: Either you are not the first and they should see the pattern even without you informing them, or it was a bad match of your PC and their website, in which case it's probably not really worth dealing with.

Answer (score 7):

> *I have to ask the HR now to modify the DOB in the contract. I am already feeling so embarrassed to ask HR about it.*

You had to input an incorrect date because of a problem from *their* side. There's nothing for you to be embarrassed about.

> *My question is do HR have to make a new contract and get the sign of my manager and director again or can this be rectified simply by writing a note on the same contract.*

We cannot say. Bring the issue up to HR and follow up with them. They would know what they need to / supposed to do.

Comment: Further suggested advice: be polite and respectful, and bring it to their attention as a pertinent fact that you think they'd wish to be aware of.  Don't demand things, don't complain, don't accuse, don't apologize.  This is you bringing something to their attention because making sure that the information is in their hands is the correct thing to do.  Cuts down on the drama all the way around, and is thus likely to get you better results and a better relationship with HR.

Comment: If you stay at the company for a very long time, you might have to wait two weeks longer for retirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your date of birth is not an integral part of the contract, and could easily be corrected by writing the correct date and initialing it with a pen.  But let HR know that you've signed it, but that the DOB needs correcting in the HR system.

Don't sweat it!